# How to add import to generated module-swift.h file?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift

I know the ProjectName-Swift.h file is generated automatically. But is there a build setting somewhere that will let me add some custom code to it? Specifically I need to add an `#import SomeFile.h`

I have a class in my -Swift.h file that is causing compiler errors because it's implementing an Objective-C protocol (from a 3rd party library) but the -Swift.h file isn't importing the header for that protocol.

Example:

```
//Swift
public class MyClass: NSObject, MyObjectiveCProtocol { ... }

//ProjectName-Swift.h file
SWIFT_CLASS("_TtC11ProjectName14MyClass")
@interface MyClass : NSObject <MyObjectiveCProtocol> ...
```

The error says "Cannot find protocol declaration for 'MyObjectiveCProtocol'" So I add `#import 'MyObjectiveCProtocol.h` to the -Swift file, but it gets removed every time I clean and build.

Is there any way that the import can be generated automatically instead of me having to do it manually? I tried adding it to the prefix file, but that felt wrong (even though it worked).

Comment: I've hit the same issue. Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Objective-C code in Swift, you need to add the `#import` to -Bridging-Header.h, not -Swift.h. As far as I know, there isn't any situation where you should be trying to manually modify -Swift.h.

See [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html) for more info.